# Why the method of my jtable getSelectedRow() don't work?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

this is my first question, so help me please. I try to save the value of the method getStelectedRow in a type int variable(row) to next can use the method getValueAt(row,column). My problem is the value of my variable, it's -1, and this means the row is not selected, but I'm selecting a row.

The error is the next:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

If need more details just say me. Thanks.

### EDIT:

My code is:

```
int row = jTablePersonal.getSelectedRow();
String query = "select * from table where id ='"+jTablePersonal.getValueAt(row,0)+"'";
```

The error point to the variable "row" when I call the method "getValueAt(row,0)"

Comment: Too much abstraction on code, not helpful to you.

Comment: When a table is created the selected row defaults to -1. So unless the user has actually clicked on a row the value will be -1. If you think you still have a problem then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @camickr I select the row, and next press a jbutton that container the code in the edit, and Netbeans throws me the error :)

Comment: ok, sorry, my code is too long xD ... I will use pastebin.com  xD .. wait a minute

Comment: @GogoMix, `my code is too long` READ MY COMMENT!!! We do not want your entire program!!! We want you to do some basic debugging. All you need is a simple example with a JTable and a JButton. The program will be about 20 lines of code. The program will compile so we can execute the code if we can't see the problem by reading the code. Once you understand the basic concept of how the getSelectedRow() method works then you debug your own code. We are not here to debug hundreds of lines of code for you.

Comment: I debug my code @camickr -_- ... and the result is -1, and this means the row is not selected and I'm selecting the wrow .. if you let me write a example and let me post it, I'm will be happy sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a newbie problem. Given your explanation

> "My problem is the value of my variable, it's -1, and this means the row is not selected, but I'm selecting a row."

You do not have this code inside a listener, you have like it your constructor or something. You want to have the code inside the listener. Something like

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        if (row != -1) {
            // do something
        }
    }
});
```

If you are using the Netbeans GUI Builder tool, you can

1. From the design view right click the button and go to `Events -> Action -> actionPerformed`
2. Go to you source view and you should see some auto-generated code like

   ```
   jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

   }
   ```

   Write the code there.

You should also take some time to read [How to write Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html). GUI Programs are event driven, so you need to learn how to respond to these events by registering listeners

Answer (score 1):

the problem is about getSelectedRow();

getSelectedRow is only work if table is current selected

my suggestion is , make temp variable to get last selectedrow to prevent error ,like

```
if(table.getSelectedRow()!=-1)
{
    int lastselected=table.getSelectedRow();
}
```